# Using batch files to copy all files from a directory tree to a single directory

Tags: batch-file, dos

I needed to copy all the files from a directory tree into a single directory. A quick search provided me with [this](https://superuser.com/questions/137336/copy-all-files-in-subfolders-to-single-folder-on-xp) method:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %a in ('dir /b /s /a-d') do @copy "%a" "c:\Single-Folder"
```

I tried it, and it worked just fine. Deciding to simplify things a bit, I created a quick batch file so I didn't have to look this up in the future. my batch file looks like this:

```
set COPY_FROM="C:\Users\me\Desktop\Disc 1"
set COPY_TO="C:\Testing\test"

cd %COPY_FROM%
for /f "tokens=*" %a in ('dir /b /s /a-d') do @copy %COPY_TO%
pause
```

Unfortunately, when I execute this, I get the error:

```
C:\Users\me\Desktop\Tools>set COPY_FROM="C:\Users\me\Desktop\Disc 1"

C:\Users\me\Desktop\Tools>set COPY_TO="C:\Testing\test"
"\Users\me\Desktop\Disc 1"') was unexpected at this time.
C:\Users\me\Desktop\Tools>for /f "tokens=*" "\Users\me\Desktop\Disc 1"') do @copy "\Testing\test"
```

What works if I enter it into the command line does not work when run as a batch file. I did try replacing the variables with the actual path, but got the same error. Even when I create a batch file with only the line that works from the command line, it doesn't work when running from the file. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
set "COPY_FROM=C:\Users\me\Desktop\Disc 1"
set "COPY_TO=C:\Testing\test"
md "%copy_to%" 2>nul
cd /d "%COPY_FROM%"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /s /a-d') do copy "%%a" "%COPY_TO%"
pause
```

Comment: The quotes in the set commands should only surround the values rather than also the variable names.

Comment: Thank you, that had the desired effect. So, in a batch file, I need to escape the % with a % and add the "do"?

Comment: There are some other niceties with quoting, a `/d` and `delims=` but essentially you had left out the source in the copy command and that two percents are needed in `for` metavariables when used in a batch file.

Comment: @AxelKemper You can try the code with quotes as they are placed.  I'm pretty sure you will find it is all legit.  When wrapping variable names the quotes are not included in the variable - and then you wrap the variable in quotes.  This makes debugging easier where you can see what is quoted and what is not.

Comment: I tried it with the variables both wrapped in quotes and not, and both ways worked. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, the quotes protect it when there are spaces, or & or other poison characters.  In your usage there is a space and they are needed when changing the directory - it is wise to get into the habit of using them all the time.  If your files have spaces etc then the `%%a` in the copy command will also need to be quoted.